# Open an ASP control inside Jquery modal dialogue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a requirement to open up a Jquery modal dialogue but it's contents needs to be either a .aspx or .ascx, is this possible?

I know that the dialogues usually open a div from the same page but I need to be able to load them up from other places and need to be able to send data to and from the modal contents as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, This should work but you need to specify. Post the code that you have to know what kind of controls are we talking about.

Comment: Well at the moment it is simply a .aspx page, I hav'nt added the jquery yet but I just need to open the page within the dialogue.

Comment: An ASPX and ASCX are two *very* different things in this case.  An ASCX is easy, because it ends up just being a control in the `div` of the modal.  An ASPX is a completely different case, because it means dynamically requesting another page (maybe with something like jQuery's `.load()` which can wreak havoc on the `form` structure of WebForms.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to place the control on another page and then load it into the dialog with iframe. ([how?](http://www.apex-at-work.com/2013/10/jquery-modaldialog-with-iframe.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.load

```
$("#mydiv").load("pageToLoad.aspx #container");
```

pageToLoad.aspx:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <!--stuff goes here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Probably it will work but haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using iframe.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

1) create separate .aspx page with content you want to show in dialog;

2) in the page add div with iframe inside it;